# cannot make curl call from post-receive in gitlab repo

Tags: ruby, bash, curl, gitlab

I have a gitlab repository. I go inside hooks folder and I see the file

```
post-receive
```

I open it and I see this at the top of the file:

```
#!/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby
```

This means that this script runs ruby-code right?

What I need to do is a simple http-post request to a server.
I can do the request from command line like this:

curl -X POST "http://myurl/job/jenkinsjob/build?token=mytoken"

However, if I put this line in the file it generates an error:

```
remote: hooks/post-receive:28: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

So I guess it is because the line I run directly from the shell is using bash, right?
So I have tried to add at the top of post-receive the bash in all possible ways. But when I do it some error occur all the time.

What I need is to do a simple post call. I can do it in ruby if required, but most sources I find are about more or less ruby programs to make a post request, and no one liners.

So, what should I do? Im open for suggestion.

Comment: Your post request don't have data why?? token should go in the way

`curl -X POST -d '{"token": "mytoken"}' "http://myurl/job/jenkinsjob/build"`

Comment: Actually the real curl looks like this: http://auto:abcd@jenkinsurl.com/job/myapp/build?token=mytoken

Answer (score 0):

Don't override the git-hooks that gitlab-omnibus provides! They're there for a reason!

[Gitlab provides a separate custom_hooks directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html) for this kind of job. You can add a script to `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<project-namespace>/<project>.git/custom_hooks/` and you can any language you want, including bash. Simply create a post-receive file in there, start it with the `#!/bin/bash` shebang you should be good to go.

Answer (score -2):

Ok I used backtick and it solved the problem:

```
`curl -X POST "http://posturl"`
```